# Sobolev diffeomorphisms.

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold without boundary.

Suppose $f \in H^s(M,M)$, where $H^s$ denotes the ($L^2$-based) Sobolev space. Assume $s > n/2 + 1$, so that by the Sobolev Embedding Theorem all maps in $H^s(M, M)$ are at least $C^1$.

**Problem**: If $f$ is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism (in addition to being $H^s$), can you show that $f^{-1}$ is also in $H^s(M, M)$?

I know that something along the lines of differentiating $f \circ f^{-1}(x) = x$ and seeing what bounds can you get from there should work, but I can't quite do the details.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a paper on this in AMS On the regularity of the composition of diffeomorphisms H. Inci, T. Kappeler, P. Topalov. I also have a stronger result on this, but I still have to cut through some problems related to manifolds.

In short the answer is yes. :)